# Need a little clarification on this Haskell code fragment

Tags: haskell

Can someone help me about what this code fragment means.
from : http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Prime_numbers#Postponed

```
primesPE1 = 2 : sieve [3..] primesPE1 
  where 
    sieve xs (p:ps) | q <- p*p , (h,t) <- span (< q) xs =
                   h ++ sieve (t `minus` [q, q+p..]) ps
                -- h ++ turner [x|x<-t, rem x p /= 0] ps
```

My question is mainly about this line:

```
sieve xs (p:ps) | q <- p*p , (h,t) <- span (< q) xs = ...
```

What that

```
 | q <- p*p , (h,t) <- span (< q) xs =
```

exactly means ? certainly that's not a guard ... it can't be a function ... & I can't understand what that construct is ( I know what it's doing, I am asking about syntax )

Thanks :-)

Comment: It appears to be two [lambdas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus#Lambda_calculus_and_programming_languages).

Comment: No, it's a guard, specifically a [pattern guard](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Pattern_guard)

Comment: This is called [Pattern guards](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Pattern_guard). Basically they are just `let` in the pattern, but a `let (Just x) = .. ` might throw a pattern match failure; if you put it in a pattern guard as `Just x <- ...`, if there is a patter match failure, it will go to the next pattern. In this case none of the pattern guards can fail anyways.

Comment: Thanks all ^_^
Got it ^_^

Comment: @user2407038: Want to add this as an answer?